# Reading pasted data onBeforePaste or onPaste

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, paste

I have the following event listener, I couldn't seem to find anything in the `ev` object that'd hold the pasted data.

```
editor.on('beforePaste', function(ev)
{
    console.log( ev );
});
```

Can I, and if yes, then how do I retrieve the posted data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `beforePaste` is fired before data are accessible. You can only find them in [`editor#paste`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste):

```
editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ) {
    console.log( evt.data.dataValue );
} );
```